# CSS material desgin like input with default value doesn't go back to original state

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a material design input but I'm having this issue with the label text, when is empty the label text should appear in the input field as placeholder, but when I assign a default value in the input, the label doesn't disappear when I clear the input.

```css
.group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* LABEL ======================================= */

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}


/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #5264AE;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~.bar:before,
input:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}


/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* ANIMATIONS ================ */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" value="default value">
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
```

made a pen to show this behaviour:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djKvYL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `required` for your input type in html which should solve your issue. We do it for `:valid` psuedo class to check if something is typed into the input box or not. As the whole thing is done in pure CSS, this `required` is necessary. Else JavaScript should have to be used for that material effect.

Also, when there will be no valid input in the textbox, shadow appears in some browsers. So, in your CSS, put `box-shadow: none;` for the input. That should solve the problem([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67opvsdk/)):

```css
body {
  margin: 40px;
}

.group {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
  box-shadow: none;
}

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" value="default value" required>
  <label>Name</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the html, you are using `value=""`. You should use `<input type="text" placeholder="default value">` instead.

```css
.group {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
}

input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}


/* LABEL ======================================= */

label {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: normal;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 5px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~label,
input:valid~label {
  top: -20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #5264AE;
}


/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */

.bar {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
}

.bar:before,
.bar:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #5264AE;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;
}

.bar:before {
  left: 50%;
}

.bar:after {
  right: 50%;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~.bar:before,
input:focus~.bar:after {
  width: 50%;
}


/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */

.highlight {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60%;
  width: 100px;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* active state */

input:focus~.highlight {
  -webkit-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation: inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}


/* ANIMATIONS ================ */

@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes inputHighlighter {
  from {
    background: #5264AE;
  }
  to {
    width: 0;
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="default value">
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
</div>
```